# Does a new user's settings affect the main user's settings?

Tags: themes, users

If I create a new user account, with different themes, icon sets, sounds, cursors and different programs, will it affect the original user's settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most settings (such as themes, icon sets, sounds, cursors, etc) are seperate for each user.

However programs installed from the *Ubuntu Software Centre* are installed system wide to all users. (Note that other software that you have manually installed, or installed through WINE may behave slightly differently.)

Comment: What ever you do with sudo,gksudo probably affect all users.

Answer (score 3):

no each user is separate. *themes are local to the user, so it will only affect the account you apply it to. if there is a script, don't use sudo*

Comment: trying my best at english,anyways.. i was asking that 'cause i read somewhere that there was a theme pack that comes with, a..well a theme,wallpapers,and icons, to make ubuntu look like OSX, but i don know if this theme packs changes something, besides the themes,settins etc. of only the "user thatś using the pack or if the changes are applied to all users.

Comment: themes are local to the user, so it will only affect the account you apply it to. if there is a script, don't use sudo.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't affect every user just the one where you are installing